# Подключаемый шаблон не видит переменную

Tags: php

Доброго вечера!

Переменная `$item_id` (определена в файле *№1* в массиве `$meta`) нужна в файле *№3*, но там о ней никто не знает. Ее там не видно. В главном шаблоне (`ROOT.'/view/main_temp.php'`, `$meta`) она есть

Прошу помощи! Как ее туда передать?

Файл *№1*:

```
<?
define(ROOT, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once ROOT.'/model/db_driver.php';
require_once ROOT.'/model/view.php';
$db = new DB_driver;
$db->connect();
//**********************************

$main = new Temp;
$content = $main->template(ROOT.'/view/catalog/adidas-5/index.php');
$meta = array(
    'title' => "Adidas",
    'description' => "Adidas",
    'content' => $content,
    'item_id' => "30",
    'parentId' => "16",
);
$page = $main->template(ROOT.'/view/main_temp.php', $meta);
echo $page;
```

Файл *№2* - `ROOT.'/view/catalog/adidas-5/index.php'` из первого файла

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div class="row">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 60px" class="col-lg-12">
        <span class="breadcrumbs">Магазин брендовой обуви</span>
        <span class="breadcrumbsR">
            <script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,twitter"></div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
<?
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/unit_temp.php';
?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Файл *№3* (его часть) - `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/unit_temp.php'` из файла *№2*

```
foreach($items as $v){
    //$item_id = "29";
    $cats = explode(',', $v['cats_str']);
    if(in_array($item_id, $cats)){
```

Comment: В таких случаях используют глобальные переменные.

Comment: @KAGG Design, добавил на главную строку setcookie('item_id', $item_id, time()+3600*24, '/'); все хорошо, кроме того, что есть опоздание на один шаг

Answer (score 0):

В главный шаблон, где видна переменная, добавил строку:

```
setcookie('item_id', $item_id, time()+3600*24, '/')
```

Все получилось. но было опоздание на один шаг. Чтобы этого не происходило, в конец файла №3 лобавил:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['page_ready'])){
    setcookie('page_ready', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], time()+3600, '/');
    header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE['page_ready'])){
    if($_COOKIE['page_ready'] != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']){
        setcookie('page_ready', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], time()+3600, '/');
        header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
}
```

Все работает, но как к переадресации относятся поисковики? Это не будет минусом для продвижения?